# Find a word that contains 5 consecutive strings in another list

Tags: python

> The word *marine* consists of five consecutive, overlapping state postal abbreviations: Massachusetts (MA), Arkansas (AR), Rhode Island (RI), Indiana (IN), and Nebraska (NE). Find a seven-letter word that has the same property.

I am using Python to open a list consisting of about 5000 words. I'd like to find a word that contains 5 states abbreviations first.

```
def puzzleH(word):
    states = ['al', 'ak', 'az', 'ar', 'ca', 'co', 'ct', 'dc', 'de', 'fl', 'ga', 
              'hi', 'id', 'il', 'in', 'ia', 'ks', 'ky', 'la', 'me', 'md', 
              'ma', 'mi', 'mn', 'ms', 'mo', 'mt', 'ne', 'nv', 'nh', 'nj', 
              'nm', 'ny', 'nc', 'nd', 'oh', 'ok', 'or', 'pa', 'ri', 'sc', 
              'sd', 'tn', 'tx', 'ut', 'vt', 'va', 'wa', 'wv', 'wi', 'wy']
    checker = 0;
    for st in states:
        if st in word:
            checker+=1
    if checker==5:
        # ...still thinking...
        #pos = (i for i,st in enumerate(word) if st in states)
        #for i in pos: print(i)
        #return word

# Main program
ListH = []
for word in wordList:
    if puzzleH(word)!=None:
        ListH.append(puzzleH(word))
```

After finding a word that contains 5 states abbreviations, I will find the index of each states abbreviation. And compare the list of these indexes to `[0,1,2,3,4]` or `[1,2,3,4,5]` or `[2,3,4,5,6]`. But I don't know how to make it.

Comment: Instead of using `st in word`, why not use `word.find( st )`, which will return the index of the match, or `-1`.  Then just store the indices as they are found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the purpose is to just identify words which consists five consecutive, overlapping state postal abbreviations, you may try something like this :

```
states = ['al', 'ak', 'az', 'ar', 'ca', 'co', 'ct', 'dc', 'de', 'fl', 'ga',
          'hi', 'id', 'il', 'in', 'ia', 'ks', 'ky', 'la', 'me', 'md',
          'ma', 'mi', 'mn', 'ms', 'mo', 'mt', 'ne', 'nv', 'nh', 'nj',
          'nm', 'ny', 'nc', 'nd', 'oh', 'ok', 'or', 'pa', 'ri', 'sc',
          'sd', 'tn', 'tx', 'ut', 'vt', 'va', 'wa', 'wv', 'wi', 'wy']

def check_word(word):
    if len(word) != 7:
        return False
    counter = 0
    for i in range(0, len(word) - 1):
        abv = word[i] + word[i + 1]
        if abv in states:
            counter += 1
            if counter == 5:
                return True
        else:
            counter = 0
    return False


for w in wordList:
    print("{0} : {1}".format(w, check_word(w)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `st in word`, why not use `word.find( st )`, which will return the index of the match, or `-1`. Then just store the indices as they are found

```
def puzzleH( word ):
    states = ['al', 'ak', 'az', 'ar', 'ca', 'co', 'ct', 'dc', 'de', 'fl', 'ga',
              'hi', 'id', 'il', 'in', 'ia', 'ks', 'ky', 'la', 'me', 'md',
              'ma', 'mi', 'mn', 'ms', 'mo', 'mt', 'ne', 'nv', 'nh', 'nj',
              'nm', 'ny', 'nc', 'nd', 'oh', 'ok', 'or', 'pa', 'ri', 'sc',
              'sd', 'tn', 'tx', 'ut', 'vt', 'va', 'wa', 'wv', 'wi', 'wy']
    found_list = []
    for st in states:
        position = word.find( st )
        if ( position != -1 ):
            found_list.append( ( st, position ) )  # <-- Keep the word + position
    if ( len( found_list ) >= 5 ):
        print("[%s]: " % ( word ) )
        for state, position in found_list:
            print( "   \"%s\" at %d" % ( state, position ) )


for word in [ 'marine', 'desert', 'dessert', 'icecream', 'chocolate', 'ohmmeter', 'comically' ]:
    puzzleH( word )
```

Which gives:

```
$ python3 ./state_find.py 
[marine]: 
   "ar" at 1
   "in" at 3
   "ma" at 0
   "ne" at 4
   "ri" at 2
```

EDIT: Testing against a Linux dictionary file:

```
words = open( '/usr/share/dict/words.pre-dictionaries-common', 'rt' ).read().split('\n')
for word in words:
    if ( word.find( "'" ) == -1 ):
        puzzleH( word )
```

Gives lots of results:

```
# (just the tail ...)
[windowpane]: 
   "in" at 1
   "ne" at 8
   "nd" at 2
   "pa" at 6
   "wi" at 0
[windowpanes]: 
   "in" at 1
   "ne" at 8
   "nd" at 2
   "pa" at 6
   "wi" at 0
[windstorms]: 
   "in" at 1
   "ms" at 8
   "nd" at 2
   "or" at 6
   "wi" at 0
[windward]: 
   "ar" at 5
   "in" at 1
   "nd" at 2
   "wa" at 4
   "wi" at 0
```

Oooh, "philandering" is a good one:

```
[philandering]: 
   "de" at 6
   "hi" at 1
   "il" at 2
   "in" at 9
   "la" at 3
   "nd" at 5
   "ri" at 8
```

**EDIT**:  It seems didn't quite read the specification perhaps as well as I should have.  The words needs to be *entirely* composed of *overlapping* state-codes.

Here's a version that fixes that.  It creates pairs of letters from the input word, looks for a state-code to match, and if found, records the position and the state-code (which is the same as before).

```
def puzzleH( word ):
    states = ['al', 'ak', 'az', 'ar', 'ca', 'co', 'ct', 'dc', 'de', 'fl', 'ga',
              'hi', 'id', 'il', 'in', 'ia', 'ks', 'ky', 'la', 'me', 'md',
              'ma', 'mi', 'mn', 'ms', 'mo', 'mt', 'ne', 'nv', 'nh', 'nj',
              'nm', 'ny', 'nc', 'nd', 'oh', 'ok', 'or', 'pa', 'ri', 'sc',
              'sd', 'tn', 'tx', 'ut', 'vt', 'va', 'wa', 'wv', 'wi', 'wy']
    found_list = []
    word_position = 0
    for i in range( len( word ) - 1 ):
        two_letters = word[i] + word[i+1]
        if ( two_letters in states ):
            found_list.append( ( two_letters, i ) )
        else:
            found_list = []
            break # word needs to be made of all state-codes

    if ( len( found_list ) >= 5 ):
        print("[%s]: " % ( word ) )
        for state, position in found_list:
            print( "   \"%s\" at %d" % ( state, position ) )

words = open( '/usr/share/dict/words.pre-dictionaries-common', 'rt' ).read().split('\n')

for word in words:
    if ( word.find( "'" ) == -1 ):
        puzzleH( word )
```

And the longest it finds is:

```
[malarial]: 
   "ma" at 0
   "al" at 1
   "la" at 2
   "ar" at 3
   "ri" at 4
   "ia" at 5
   "al" at 6
```

Interestingly there's only 4 words (of >= 5 codes) in that entire 73,000 word  dictionary.

Comment: But it's not  consecutive and overlapping. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Yes, good point.  (D'oh!)  - Wait, does the word have to *completely* made of state codes?

Comment: hi @Kingsley, appreciate your work. Is there anyway that I can send you notification when I post a question in the future? It would be nice to learn from you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dict that maps state abbreviations to indices, then iterate through pairs of adjacent letters of a given word by zipping the word with itself but with an offset of 1, look up the pair of letters in the dict, and if found, add the corresponding index to the output list:

```
state_indices = {state: index for index, state in enumerate(states)}
def puzzleH(word):
    indices = []
    for pair in zip(word, word[1:]):
        candidate = ''.join(pair)
        if candidate not in state_indices:
            break
        indices.append(state_indices[candidate])
    else:
    return indices

for word in wordList:
    indices = puzzleH(word)
    if indices is not None:
        print(word, indices)
```